# Puntuación al "romper" un párrafo con una cita o ejemplo

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, uso-de-mayúsculas

En este y muchos otros *stacks*, es relativamente habitual en respuestas largas incluir los ejemplos y citas en sus respectivos bloques, lo cual a veces "rompe" el párrafo en el que se encuentran.

Por ejemplo, si yo escribo: *«Esto no rompe el párrafo.»*, no rompo el párrafo, y continúo con una coma y en minúscula como en cualquier otro texto. Sin embargo, si en lugar de comillas y cursiva decido usar un bloque de cita y escribo:

> *Esto sí rompe el párrafo.*

, sí rompo el párrafo, y es aquí donde me surge la duda: **¿es correcto esto que acabo de hacer, de continuar con coma y minúscula escribiendo *«, sí rompo ...»***  (igual que en el ejemplo previo a este escribí *«, no rompo ...»*)? ¿O, por el contrario, el hecho de romper artificialmente el párrafo obliga a comenzar en mayúscula, y por tanto debería haber escrito *«Sí rompo»* aunque esté continuando la misma oración que comencé antes del bloque?

Y ya que estamos, tampoco es raro encontrarse casos en los que ni siquiera se usan los dos puntos para introducir el bloque, escribiendo

> algún ejemplo

y siguiendo como si tal cosa. ¿Es correcto esto también?

¿Qué normas de puntuación y mayúsculas se aplican en estos casos?

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer, debe introducirse por un signo de dos puntos.

Del artículo del DPD en *dos puntos*:

> [**Dos puntos**](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2a3yRXFBiD6rvDOMtq).
>
> 1. Usos lingüísticos
>
> 1.3. Preceden a la reproducción de citas o palabras textuales, que deben escribirse entre comillas e iniciarse con mayúscula (→ [mayúsculas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp), 3.3c): *Ya lo dijo Ortega y Gasset: «La claridad es la cortesía del filósofo»*.

De esta entrada extraemos el hecho de que toda reproducción de las que mencionas debe introducirse por dos puntos y cursiva/comilla.

Por tanto, dados los textos de tu pregunta, este es correcto:

> Sin embargo, si en lugar de comillas y cursiva decido usar un bloque de cita y escribo:
>
> > *Esto sí rompe el párrafo.*

Pero este incorrecto:

> ... para introducir el bloque, escribiendo
>
> > algún ejemplo

Y debería escribirse:

> ... para introducir el bloque, escribiendo:
>
> > Algún ejemplo

---

En cuanto a cómo escribir *tras* la cita, eso no está pautado explícitamente, pero el hecho que la cita sea un frase completa, con sus signos de puntuación, hace que todo lo que venga a continuación deba ser considerado una frase nueva, de ahí que yo optaría por empezar por mayúscula.

Answer (score 2):

Coincido con [la respuesta de @fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28414/12637), pero además te voy a poner una captura de pantalla de la *Gramática* de la RAE para que veas cómo trata este tema:

[image: Gramática]

Como verás, los bloques de comentario en la *Gramática* equivalen a los párrafos indentados. Siempre se preceden por dos puntos, y el texto continúa después con una nueva frase, dado que las citas terminan siempre con un punto (si cortas la cita antes de que termine la frase, se suele añadir al final "[...]."). Sin embargo, si la cita es sin romper el párrafo, sí se puede continuar la frase después, como se ve en la imagen:

> En ciertos contextos, admite paráfrasis con *solo*, *nada más que* o *no más que*, como en *Dicen que por las noches / nomás se le iba en un puro llorar* (Obando, *Paraíso*), es decir 'nada más que en llorar'.

En este caso se usa texto en cursiva para delimitar la cita, el cual la RAE prefiere antes que las comillas, que se reservan para los casos en los que la cursiva no es posible.

Comment: Sobre la parte final, efectivamente el DPD dice en [comillas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX): _En los textos impresos, en lugar de usar las comillas, se escribe el término en un tipo de letra diferente al de la frase en que va inserto (en cursiva si el texto normal va en redonda, o en redonda si el texto normal va en cursiva)_.